# How can I run many asynchronous methods all together?

Tags: c#

I want to run my asynchronous methods GetPlayerCountryData() and GetPlayerTagsData() all together to save time instead of starting the next method only after the previous has completed. But I don't know how to do that.

https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2019/03/11/using-async-await-and-task-whenall-to-improve-the-overall-speed-of-your-c-code/

I have read this tutorial but I don't know how to use await Task.WhenAll() in my code.

In addition, I want to execute the line AllMethodsCompleted = true; after all my asynchronous methods have been completed successfully. Should I use await Task.WhenAll() in this situation?

How can I only set AllMethodsCompleted = true if all my asynchronous methods completed successfully? Is it possible to find out if (result.Error != null) or an exception occurred in one of the asynchronous methods before setting AllMethodsCompleted = true ?

```
string PlayerDeviceId = "";

private void RegisterGuestPlayFabAccount()
{
    PlayerDeviceId = ReturnMobileID();
    var requestIOS = new LoginWithIOSDeviceIDRequest { DeviceId = PlayerDeviceId, CreateAccount = true };
    var loginTask = PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithIOSDeviceIDAsync(requestIOS);
    loginTask.ContinueWith(OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete);
}

private void OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete(Task<PlayFabResult<LoginResult>> task)
{
    if (task.Result.Result != null)
    {
        PlayerAccountDetails();
    }

    if (task.Result.Error != null)
    {
        OnPlayFabError(task.Result.Error);
    }
}

 bool AllMethodsCompleted = false;

 public async void PlayerAccountDetails()
 {
     await GetPlayerCountryData();
     await GetPlayerTagsData();
     AllMethodsCompleted = true;
 }

 private async Task GetPlayerTagsData()
 {
     var resultprofile = await PlayFabServerAPI.GetPlayerTagsAsync(new PlayFab.ServerModels.GetPlayerTagsRequest()
     {
         PlayFabId = PlayerPlayFabID
     });

     if (resultprofile.Error != null)
         OnPlayFabError(result.Error);
     else
     {
         if ((resultprofile.Result != null) && (resultprofile.Result.Tags.Count() > 0))
             CurrentPlayerTag = resultprofile.Result.Tags[0].ToString();
     }
 }

 private async Task GetPlayerCountryData()
 {
     var resultprofile = await PlayFabClientAPI.GetUserDataAsync(new PlayFab.ClientModels.GetUserDataRequest()
     {
         PlayFabId = PlayerPlayFabID,
         Keys = null
     });

     if (resultprofile.Error != null)
         OnPlayFabError(result.Error);
     else
     {
         if (resultprofile.Result.Data == null || !resultprofile.Result.Data.ContainsKey("Country") || !resultprofile.Result.Data.ContainsKey("City"))
             Console.WriteLine("No Country/City");
         else
         {
             PlayerCountry = resultprofile.Result.Data["Country"].Value);
             PlayerCity = resultprofile.Result.Data["City"].Value);
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: PlayerAccountDetails is `async void` and that's a very bad idea. There are very few occasions where `async void` is valid to use. This is not one of them. Make it return a Task instead, and await any asynchronous calls it makes.

Comment: I changed it to public async Task PlayerAccountDetails(). What should I change so that GetPlayerCountryData() and GetPlayerTagsData() are not executed one after another, but simultaneously?  But AllMethodsCompleted = true can only be executed if GetPlayerCountryData() and GetPlayerTagsData() are already completed.

Comment: By not awaiting the calls immediately - they are executed asynchronously. So you don't have to worry about that. You really can simplify a lot of this code - what is calling RegisterGuestPlayFabAccount? You haven't shown that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async Task PlayerAccountDetails()
{ 
    var playerCountryData = GetPlayerCountryData());
    var playerTagsData = GetPlayerTagsData());        

    await Task.WhenAll(playerCountryData, playerTagsData);
    AllMethodsCompleted = true;
}
```

Here is the method you are in query about and running the 2 methods in async waiting for each to finish then moving on. They just needed to be assigned to a task variable.

Comment: This method being `async void` will prevent it from working as you intended - that should be fixed. And posting answers without an explanation is highly discouraged.

Comment: Why downvote when I was answering the question. Also explanation has been added.

Comment: Downvotes are used as the user sees fit. Simply attempting to answer a question doesn't protect you from receiving a downvote - otherwise we wouldn't have them in the first place. You still have yet to address my point regarding the `async void` usage.

Comment: Changed to Task

Comment: Now you changed it to a task - but you haven't explained that you need to await it where it's called - and that needs to be awaited and so forth, all the way up the call stack.

Comment: What happens if one of the methods fails? How can I find out in Task.WhenAll if a method failed?

Comment: @mason I can not await PlayerAccountDetails() where it's called because it is not possible to use await in OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountComplete. Error CS4033: The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: @Tobey60 Exactly my point. Did you read the error message? It suggests marking OnPlayFabRegisterGuestAccountCompleteas async. Go mark that as async. Anywhere you call that method, make sure you await it. And so forth, all the way up the callstack until you get to an event handler. Make sure you also await any other asynchronous calls, such as PlayFabClientAPI.LoginWithIOSDeviceIDAsync.

Comment: @Tobey60 You accepted this answer far too soon. It's going to cause you problems. You need to follow proper async/await patterns: all asynchronous calls must be awaited. By taking the code that user10127407 suggested, you've got no way of handling an error thrown by the logic invoked by PlayerAccountDetails. You won't see any exceptions. It will just be lost and be extremely difficult to debug when you come back to this later.

Comment: @Tobey60 I suggest you follow some async/await tutorials and read [Async Await Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming). Many people get async/await wrong and they don't realize their mistakes and they then try to pass that flawed knowledge on to others. Take the time to learn it properly so you can avoid falling into that trap.